# My site is slowing down randomly and graphs show no load

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nginx, linode

I have a problem, My site starts lagging at random times, the server shows no signs of CPU load or hard disk swapping during I/O, I just upgraded the server (768 Linode) yet the site lags, anyone in the field have any idea of what could be the cause? I am leaning towards increasing PHP's memory access limits but I don't think it's the cause.

I am using nginx, the access log size is like 600MBs should I disable that?

What else could be the cause? I mean my site is small right now but it's facing terrible slow downs.

Edit: I am running on VPS Linode 768, No memcache only MySQL and PHP, Lagging is like the site does not load, a page takes like 24-50 seconds to load.

Site: http://scapehouse.com

Comment: Nope, latency is not the thing also When I reboot the server the site is fast for a few mins before becoming slow again. Also the thing is there are not a lot of users online at one time. maximum like 30-40 right now.

Comment: what you have provided is too little to consider a question, you need to specify external resources (memcache, databases)

Comment: Is this is a dedicated physical server? or a virtual one? shared?

Comment: What is your definition of 'lagging'? Also how have you deduced it is lagging? By what testing methods?

Comment: @Marc B, it's VPS (XEN). http://linode.com And it's the best hosting.

Comment: @ajreal lags of databases will be reflected on CPU and/or IO usage graph.

Comment: @oz: given it's a VPS, you'll be affected by what's going on in the other VMs running on the same physical hardware. Your own server could be perfectly well behaved, but suffering because someone in another VM is sucking up resources like there's no tomorrow.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, the database could be sitting at another server

Comment: @Marc B, yes, but Linode have very good support and they will immediately move "bad" VPS to another host, so I'm not sure that this behaviour could be long enough to make OP write question here.

Comment: @ajreal yes, you right, but then lags should be reflected on graphs of that "another server", right?

Comment: Edit: I am running on VPS Linode 768, No memcache only MySQL and PHP, Lagging is like the site does not load, a page takes like 24-50 seconds to load.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your scripts uses some API through HTTP - try to add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

as **FIRST** lines into `/etc/resolve.conf` file to reduce time of resolving domains. It was solution for me once (I use Linode too).